# Есть ли слово "псица"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как-то в тексте попалось слово "псица" — женский род от слова "пес". Есть ли вообще такое слово в русском языке?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Словари современного русского языка дают его как устаревшее. Словарь  Ушакова -  как областное (диалектное). Т. е. в современном языке это слово вне активного употребления.

Comment: Браво. Никогдла бы не подумал, что слово не выдумано. Меня не часто можно так ошеломить.

Comment: Коняга, коняжка, коняжечка.

*Редкая псица доплывет до середины Днепра.*

Comment: @behemothus, **кобыла**. Конь этимологически из komnъ < kobnъ после упрощения группы согласных, bn > н.

Comment: >Интересно, а для "конь" есть женский род?
КонЯка.

Comment: Коняка, коняга и проч. - это вряд ли женское к конь... Просто "фамильярное обращение" к коню, какой-то непритязательный конь. Потому, что суффикс "як (ак)", а он не несет "женской" семантики (ср. гуляка, котяка, даже свиняка).  Аналогично "коняха" - это какой-то непритязательный конь.

Должно быть что-то типа конИха, конИца, в крайнем случае - конька.

Comment: >кобыла.     
  
Кобыла не катит. Это женское к жеребец.  Нужно какое-то слово, которое образовалось уже после того, как конь стало обозначать именно коня, т.е. жербеца, . Исторически-то конь было названием для обоих полов (и вроде бы даже женского грамматического рода). Как нынче, скажем, "кошки" - это и коты, и кошки, и котята.   
Когда появилась лошадь, она потеснила историческое "конь". Вот ка этом этапе и могло образоваться нечто подобное "псице". Но, вроде, не зафиксировано.

Comment: Певец- певица,красавец- красавица, умелец- умелица. Слово псица есть. Может,и  псец был?

Comment: Конь — это обозначения и для женского, и для мужского рода (например, в украинском языке вообще нет слово "лошадь", а есть только "кiнь". Поэтому все-таки — кобыла.  
Но я с удивлением узнала, что от слова "пес", которое я считала аналогичным слову "конь" есть женский род.

Comment: >Слово псица есть. Может,и псец был?
Маленький северный зверёк :-)

>кобыла

Что-то я такое читал, что *кобыла*, *могила* -- это странные слова. Непонятного происхождения. Читал давно и не помню где, поэтому за достоверность не ручаюсь. Там подвели к тому, что это из какого-нибудь древнего исчезнувшего языка. Может быть из языка Триполья. Правда про эту Трипольскую культуру сейчас столько фантастики придумывают...

Comment: Не могу прокомментировать. Был бы источник - еще бы попытался. А так... Ниеизветстно кем неизвестно что сказано...

Comment: @FuchoinKazuki Конь и лошадь - это названия животного, но слова имеют разный грамматический род (мужской и женский соответственно), что отражает их использование в речи относительно животного конкретного пола. В украинском для обозначения женской особи обычно используется слово "кобила".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, а что значит нет слова "гендер"?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: ну русские такое не нужно, есть "род".

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, ну слово-то есть во всех словарях, и не случайно, так как "пол", а тем более "род" не могут заменить значение этого социально-культурно-психологического термина (феномена).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: ой, пол, конечно, имел в виду!